# CakePHP 3 Embedded Video File Not Showing

Tags: php, html, cakephp, video

I am trying to embed a video file using cakephp 3 for helper with this :

```
<?= 

$this->Html->media('video.mp4', [

    'fullBase' => true,

    'text' => 'Fallback text'

]) ?>
```

According to the doc [#linking-to-videos-and-audio-files](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-videos-and-audio-files) but nothing is showing up.

My video file in in `files/video.mp4`, is there anything I am missing?

Comment: First check whether the generated HTML looks like expected, then check your browsers network console to figure out whether the request for the file is successful or not (any errors, unexpected data, etc).

Answer (score 0):

1. On a computer, go to the YouTube video you want to embed.
2. Under the video, click Share.
3. Click Embed.
4. From the box that appears, copy the HTML code.
5. Paste the code into your blog or website HTML.